# Maven build of Saiku open source project fails second time after no changes

Tags: java, linux, maven

I was doing a build yesterday for the second time of an open source project (Saiku) – I have made no changes to the POM.XML or any of the libraries/jars. The build succeeded a few days ago but now fails. The following pastebin shows the output. The errors are of two types – failure to delete /clean project, and cannot find artifact. Does anyone have any troubleshooting tips?

**http://pastebin.com/g2bpAtMS**

**error type 1**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project saiku-core: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/target/javadoc-bundle-options/javadoc-options-javadoc-resources.xml
```

**error Type 2**

```
  - [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
  - [ERROR]   The project org.saiku:saiku-webapp:2.2-SNAPSHOT (/usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-webapp/pom.xml) has 1 error
  - [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.saiku:saiku-core:pom:2.2-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 10 -> [Help 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you building within your local repo?  That would be bad.

I get similar errors because, I think, my virus checker locks a file underneath the target/ directory and clean cannot delete the directory.  I delete the directory manually and resume the build.

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to delete /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-core/target/javadoc-bundle-options/javadoc-options-javadoc-resources.xml
```

You have locked this file. Close every program which could have opened it.

```
Failed to delete /usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-ui/target/classes/routers/QueryRouter.js
```

Idem for this file.

```
/usr/local/.m2/repository/saiku/saiku-server/target/saiku-server-foodmart-2.2-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz
```

Idem for this file.

```
Could not find artifact org.saiku:saiku-core:pom:2.2-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

It seems you have changed something : Maven does not find the parent pom referenced by relativePath attribute.

Check these errors, you always many errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed that by setting **relativePath** in pom.xml of saiku-webapp:

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>saiku-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.saiku</groupId>
        <version>2.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../saiku-core/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```